# Dynamic Tooltip in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, xaml, tooltip, silverlight-5.0

I have a tooltip that I have to set through code like that :

```
private ToolTip _tooltip;
private void btnTest_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

    if (_tooltip == null)
    {
        _tooltip = CreateToolTip();
        ToolTipService.SetToolTip(btnTest, _tooltip);

        _tooltip.IsOpen = true;
    }

}

private void btnTest_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (_tooltip != null)
        _tooltip.IsOpen = false;
}
```

The first time it enters the btnTest, the tooltip gets create and is associated to btnTest.  Then we need to set `IsOpen = true` to show the tooltip immediately.

When the mouse leaves the button it sets `IsOpen = false`.

This is working fine, but my btnTest is likely to disapear at anytime, so if we set its Visibility = Collapsed while the "first" tooltip is opened,  the tooltip will remain opened (the MouseLeave will never be called)

Comment: What's your ultimate goal? Because it seems over-complicated in what you're trying to do to what it appears is the requirement in regards to using the tooltipservice

Comment: I need to create them dynamically since there is about a thousand control to display at once.  i need performance. And creating the tooltip (in xaml side) is really time consuming

Comment: `<Button.ToolTip><ToolTip><TextBlock Text="{Binding Blah}"/><!-- or whatever --></ToolTip></Button.ToolTip>` is more time consuming?

Comment: Well there is a lot more than a simple textblock in my Tooltip.  So yeah its more time consuming, it has to parse the xaml within the tooltip.  I don't want to create all this stuff in the tooltip when I don't need it (especially to those 1000 items)

Comment: That's what a template is for, it's only loaded once, only thing that would change is the content, but no worries man, everyone has their own ways. Best of luck.

Comment: @ChrisW. Event if using a template it is slower!  Just try creating a simple ItemsControl with a DataTemplate containing a textblock.  Bind it to a source with 1000 elements.  Adding a <ToolTipService.Tooltip><Tooltip>blablabla</Tooltip></TooltipService.Tooltip> on the textblock will consume more time

Comment: It wasn't in reference to the loading of your data amigo, you're still going to have to look into using virtualization like a `VirtualizingStackPanel` and if your question is actually about the speed in which your elements load you should form it more towards such. It's not the tooltip slowing you down, it's loading all your stuff at once with unreasonable expectation in performance while doing so.

Comment: How is the button collapsed? Why can't you do something like `if (btnTest.ToolTip != null) btnTest.ToolTip.IsOpen = false;` in whatever method is causing the button to be collapsed in the first place?

Comment: @ChrisW.  Thank you, but the overall problem is much more complex to explain, my controls (which are all templated control) are in an ESRI maps control (not in a simple virtualizing stackpanel) and when zooming out and panning a LOT of objects gets created/removed from the map. I need optimal performance to pan smoothly. I used that example to clarify what I need simply.

Comment: @klugerama my controls are appearing/disapearing from the UI since they are binded to an object collection that is constantly modified.

Comment: So attach a `PropertyChanged` event handler to the button in the constructor or when the button is created, and put something like `if (e.PropertyName.Equals("Visibility")) { var btnTest = sender as Button; if (btnTest.ToolTip != null) btnTest.ToolTip.IsOpen = false; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `Unloaded` event. It will be fired no matter whether the button is removed from the view or just set to `Collapsed`.

```
private ToolTip _tooltip;
private void btnTest_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

    if (_tooltip == null)
    {
        _tooltip = CreateToolTip();
        ToolTipService.SetToolTip(btnTest, _tooltip);
        btnTest.Unloaded += CloseAndDetachTooltip;
    }
    _tooltip.IsOpen = true;
}

private void CloseAndDetachTooltip(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    TryCloseTooltip();
    ToolTipService.SetToolTip(btnTest, null);
    _tooltip = null;
}

private void TryCloseTooltip()
{
    if (_tooltip != null) _tooltip.IsOpen = false;
}

private void btnTest_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    TryCloseTooltip();
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, I already found that on friday, but it really seems like the best way to do it. I awarded you for the bounty, thanks.